# Replace an expression with special characters by another in shell script or sed

Tags: bash, sed, special-characters

In a file `x`, a line containing `4*4 4*1 4*4 4*0` is to be replaced by `4*4 4*1 3*4 1*4 4*0` which is in file `y`. I'm using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
old=`grep "4*4" x`;
new=`grep "4*4" y`;
sed -i "s/${old}/${new}/g" x
```

but it yields no change at all in `x`. I'm a novice and this might be a silly  question for this site but I'm unable to replace this expression with multiple special characters with another expression.

Comment: `*` is a special char, a quantifier, you need to escape it, ``\*``.

Comment: `4*4` means "`4` zero or more times followed by `4`" to `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackOverflow - An awesome platform for developers 

If you stick around, you will also find it very rewarding.

Now to your question.

`*` is a special character for `sed` when it is included in **pattern to match**. More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script#33005).

Thus, we need to escape it with a `\`.

You can use something like `old=$(echo "${old}" | sed -r 's/[*]/\\*/g')` to do so for each `*` inside variable `old`.

- `echo "${old}" |` feeds the value of variable `old` to `sed`.
- Let me write the `sed` command in an expanded form: `sed -r` `'s/` `[*]` `/` `\\*` `/g'`

  - `-r` because we are using `regex` in **pattern to match**.
  - `[*]` is the `regex` and also the **pattern to match**. [Info](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)
  - `\\*` is the **replacement string** - The first `\` is escaping the second `\` and `*` is being treated as a normal character.
- `$(  )` has been used to assign the final output to variable `old`.

Here is the **modified script**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read the strings
old=`grep "4*4" x`;
new=`grep "4*4" y`;

# Escape * i.e. add \ before it - As * is a special character for sed
old=$(echo "${old}" | sed -r 's/[*]/\\*/g')

# Replace
sed -i "s/${old}/${new}/g" x
```

Comment: Since this is Bash, we can just use parameter substition: `${old//\*/\\*}`. See my (related) [answer to *sed replace with variable with multiple lines*](/a/39269241).

Comment: @TobySpeight The `sed` version is much more readable for a web + mobile dev like me. I agree that bash's parameter substitution will always be faster than any other method. Matter of which trade off you want to take 

Comment: Hmm... To the person who down voted my answer: Can you please tell me the reason? So that I can improve it.