# Bash: issue with sed on encountering '&'

Tags: bash

I have a config file which I use to store key values which is then over written on actual properties file. I have below code which I use for this purpose and this works fine for key values which does not have '&' in it.

Get the desired value from the config file:

```
postgresql_url=$(grep "^postgresql.url=" ./<file_name> |cut -d= -f2,3,4,5)
```

the above code gives me:

```
jdbc:postgresql://ec2-22-222-2-22.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:111/d3bxxxx2cj1?password=xyz&user=user1&sslmode=require
```

I am trying to over write the below value with the one from above

```
app1.postgresql.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-11-111-1-139.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:222/d53hyyyy928s0?password=abc&user=user1&sslmode=require
```

sed: however gives me this output after replacing:

```
sed -i -e '/postgresql.url[[:blank:]]*=/ s|=.*|='$postgresql_url'|' $property_file
```

Result:

```
app1.postgresql.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-22-222-2-22.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:111/d3bxxxx2cj1?password=xyz=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-11-111-1-139.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:222/d53hyyyy928s0?password=abc&user=user1&sslmode=requireuser=user1=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-11-111-1-139.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:222/d53hyyyy928s0?password=abc&user=user1&sslmode=requiresslmode=require
```

As you can see the replace it not what is required. How to ignore '&' in sed replacement and get below result:

```
app1.postgresql.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-22-222-2-22.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:111/d3bxxxx2cj1?password=xyz&user=user1&sslmode=require
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about escaping `&` (a.k.a adding `\` before each `&`) in the replacement string for `sed`?

A bit explanation about escaping special characters inside a variable using `sed` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628567/replace-an-expression-with-special-characters-by-another-in-shell-script-or-sed/52634016#52634016).

Here is a sample script for your case:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir temp && cd temp

# Create the property file (in which url needs to be replaced)
echo 'app1.postgresql.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-11-111-1-139.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:222/d53hyyyy928s0?password=abc&user=user1&sslmode=require' >> property


# The new url
postgresql_url='jdbc:postgresql://ec2-22-222-2-22.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:111/d3bxxxx2cj1?password=xyz&user=user1&sslmode=require'

# Escape &
postgresql_url=$(echo "${postgresql_url}" | sed -r 's/[&]/\\&/g')


# For sed
pattern='app1\.postgresql\.url=.*$'
replacement="app1.postgresql.url=${postgresql_url}"

# Replace
sed -i -r "s;${pattern};${replacement};g" property
```

Comment: excellent..this is exactly what i want, escaping does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @VV- Glad that it helped you. Can you mark my answer as **accepted** if the problem is solved?

Comment: Since we're in Bash, we can just perform substitution in the parameter expansion `${postgresql_url//&/\\&}` - much cheaper than a subshell for `sed`.

Comment: See my (related) [answer to *sed replace with variable with multiple lines*](/a/39269241).

Comment: Agree. This eliminates additional subshell. Thanks.